# Adding multiple validation in react component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-component

I am using one tutorial react component, where validation is baked in component. I am getting issue I can do only one type of validation, but I want to do multiple validation.

My component's render is

```
    <Input
          hintText={this.props.hinttext}
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
```

And onChange method is this

```
  onChange = (evt) => {
    const name= this.props.name;
    const value = evt.target.value;
    const error = this.props.validate ? this.props.validate(value) : false;
    this.setState({value, error});
    this.props.onChange({name, value, error});
  }
```

Now I am using this in my form with following methods

```
          <Field
            placeholder="Email"
            name='email'
            value={this.state.fields.email}
            onChange={this.onInputChange}
            validate={(val) => (isEmail(val) ? false: 'Invalid Email')}
          />
```

This will do validation of email, while if I need another type of validtion I can change validate like following

```
            validate={(val) => (val ? false : 'Name Required')}
```

All working, but I want to define both validations for one field, I am noticing it is arrow function and I should add multiple values but not sure how to do it, as I am not good in ES6. Any suggestion.

Comment: This may help you - https://medium.com/code-monkey/client-side-form-validation-in-react-40e367de47ba

Comment: I already checked it but that will change all my coding, and I have feeling that this solution with component is much easier and better, so I want to add another validation option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to run a custom validator with the validation that you needed as below

```
function validator(val) {
  this.error = [];
  this.val = val;
  this.isRequired = function(){
    if (!this.val) {
      this.error.push('This field is required');
    }
    return this;
  }
  this.isEmail = function() {
   const filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
   if (this.val && !filter.test(this.val)) {
      this.error.push('Invalid Email');
   }
   return this;
  }
  return this;
}
```

and call the validator in the validate attributes

```
<Field
    placeholder="Email"
    name='email'
    value={this.state.fields.email}
    onChange={this.onInputChange}
    validate={(val) => new validator(val).isRequired().isEmail().error}
/>
```

Comment: So I have to put this validator function in each form. Thank you will check it.

Comment: This is working but I am getting issue in my material-ui it remain still red due to `  const error = this.props.validate ? this.props.validate(value) : false;` as props.validate is also using validate function.

Comment: How can we display if on specific input field if i am rendering it with the help of map.?